# Can't run Classic ASP on IIS 7 Windows Server 2008 64 Bit

Tags: iis-7, asp-classic, windows-server-2008

We have a couple of web apps built in Classic ASP which are currently running on Windows Server 2003 32 Bit and IIS 6.

We are trying to migrate this to a new server running Windows Server 2008 64 Bit with IIS 7. But we are finding it very difficult to make Classic ASP work on IIS 7 in a 64 Bit OS.

I got to a tage where running the following code:

```
<%

Response.Write "This is the new www5"
Response.End

%>
```

Gives us an error on Response.End

```
This is the new www5 error '8002801d' 

/test.asp, line 4
```

I have enabled 32bit Applications, also registered a few times asp.dll running regsvr32.exe but no luck so far.

Tried restaring IIS, recycling the application pool after each config change but nothing.

Thanks in advance.

Federico

Comment: I am slightly concerned that your manual registering of asp.dll may have caused you more problems that it would have solved.  2008 R2 runs Classic ASP apps fine in 64-bit, so it's not a generic problem and may be something specific about your setup.

Do you have a spare box you can install from fresh with 2k8 R2 and just install the bare minimum (IIS + Classic ASP, no need for IIS6 elements mentioned below)?

Comment: I've done this on more than one VM already using 2008R2 and had to follow the same procedure every time I'm afraid.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the end it turned out to be a permission issue on the registry.

I googled a bit more and found that 8002801d error means than a library is not registered or not properly registered.

I used procmon to monitor the access to the registry and found out that a key under HKCR\TypeLib was getting access denied.

Then i tried to run regedt32 to add the permissions for the IIS USR to that key, but was getting access denied as well.

So I downloaded PSTOOLS and run the following command: psexec -s -i regedt32

That opened regedt32 without having any access denied popups and added the IIS USR to that key.

After doing this Classic ASP is working on IIS 7 Windows Server 2008 64 Bit.

Cheers,
Federico

Comment: Holy hot damn. I'm glad I didn't have to go through that. I'm using ASP on IIS7 and Server 2003 (64 bit) and don't have that problem ... but maybe this will come in handy when migrating to 2008.

Answer (score 0):

Do this Step by Step:

Go to control panel
Windows features on/off
Tick this features:

3.a) Internet Information Service>Web management tools>IIS6 Management Compatibility

3.b) Internet Information Service>Web management tools>IIS Management Console

3.c) Internet Information Service>Worldwide web services>Application dev. features>ASP

3.d) Internet Information Service>Worldwide web services>Application dev. features>ISAPI Extentions

Answer (score 0):

To solve this issue you should change the application pool to "classic asp" in IIS settings and also change the application 64bit to 32bit.

Comment: There is no need to force 32-bit mode unless you are using third-party COM objects that aren't 64-bit enabled.  That said, you can still make them accessible to 64-bit apps anyway, so there is no need for this at all.

Comment: Hi Guys, In the end it was a permission issue in one of the registry keys. I used procmon to track the registry access and I found one key getting access denied. I then had to download pstools to access the regedit without getting access denied on the key, added the iis user to that key allowed users and it worked!